# WPF - Cross Thread Event

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, canvas

My problem is that I want to add Items in a Canvas, using a new thread. So i have multiple Methods (an example at the bottom), they generate for example an Image and set some properties. Then they should callback the generated think through an event.

The following is a part of the thread i call to generate thinks for the canvas:

```
    //Here I create the event in the seconde Thread

    public delegate void OnItemGenerated(UIElement elem);

    public event OnItemGenerated onItemGenerated;

    public void ItemGenerated(UIElement ui)
    {
        if (onItemGenerated != null)
            onItemGenerated(ui);
    }

    ......

    //This is how I generate for example an image

   public void addImage(int x, int y, string path, int width, int height)
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(path);
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Source = getImage(bitmap);
        img.Width = width;
        img.Height = height;
        Canvas.SetTop(img, y);
        Canvas.SetLeft(img, x);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { ItemGenerated(img); }), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
    }
```

Then on the main thread I want to add the callbacked UIElement to the canvas.

```
banner.onItemGenerated += (ui) =>
        {
            var uiElem = ui;
            this.canvas.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate () { this.canvas.Children.Add(uiElem); }));
        };
```

And this is how I start the Thread:

```
Thread t2 = new Thread(delegate ()
        {
            banner.GenerateImage(p);      
        });
        t2.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t2.Start();
```

Why I do this is because some Elements need to connect to a TelNet connection. And this takes some time, so I want to add the Elements in the Canvas asyncronly.

The problem is that i cant access the Canvas because it says that i try to access a different thread.

*Sorry, English is not my first language.*

Comment: It is unclear what problem you are having. One should invoke back to the GUI thread to do any gui work and your code does that. So what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry i think i forget that O.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use the `Canvas` item directly because it lives in the gui thread. The invoke you want to use should be generic one such as this one which I have as a static on my ViewModel:

```
public static void SafeOperationToGuiThread(Action operation)
{
    System.Windows.Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Invoke(operation);
}
```

Then you can call the operation from the other thread such as:

```
SafeOperationToGuiThread(() =>
{
       var uiElem = ui;
       canvas.Children.Add(uiElem);                
});
```

Comment: Thx for you answer. I tried it before, but it didnt worked.

Comment: @user3407757 Just remember, anything GUI related has to be done on the GUI thread. Meaning that you can't create GUI objects on  a different thread. I think you are doing that somewhere...and getting the exception.

Comment: I got the exeption in the Event I created. So is there an possibillity to create a event between two threads?

Comment: @user3407757. No, one has to create an event in a separate thread. Even accessing `read` only data on controls can give an exception. You need to re-think your design to separate out the concerns. All gui activities have to run on the GUI thread. :-|